# How can I build query by the lowest hierarchy level?

Tags: php, laravel

On the frontend there is a table that shows information about users and their position in the company.

There are 4 dropdowns for each level of company hierarchy:
`groups`, `units`, `departments`, `teams`.

These dropdowns are meant to filter out users to display in the table from the selected hierarchy.

Each dropdown has its unique identifier like `group1`, `unit4`, `department10`, `team99`.
Each hierarchy holds data about its ancestors. For example, `team99` belongs to `department10`, which belongs to   `unit4` which belongs to `group1`.

Then if `team99` is selected, it will be an array that contains all of its ancestors: `unit4`, `department10` and `group1`.

From each of these selections I need to build a select query:

```
foreach ($selections as $selection) {
$fullQuery->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where("group", "=", $selection->group) //"group1"
        ->where("unit", "=", $selection->unit) //"unit4"
        ->where("department", "=", $selection->department) //"department10"
        ->where("team", "=", $selection->team) //"team99"
    })
}
```

The dropdowns in the frontend are free selections so a user can first choose the `team` and then choose `group`.

In this case the returned `$selections` would be an array containing `group1` alone, and another array containing `group1`, `unit4`, `deprtment10` and `team99`.

If I don't filter the results beforehand, the query builder would be both for where `group = group1` or where all the others (`group1`, `unit4`, `department10`, `team99`).

But this is not what I want, I need to build the query with the lowest of selections.

How can I prepare the data such that it will ignore the unnecessary hierarchies?

Another example:

received input:

```
[
   ["group2"],
   ["group2", "unit11", "department50", "team10"],
   ["group2", "unit11", "department50", "team58"],
   ["group2", "unit10"],
   ["group5", "unit23"],
   ["group5", "unit23", "department101"]
]
```

Then I will need to build a query from the lowest hierarchies, in this case:

```
   ["group2", "unit11", "department50", "team10"],
   ["group2", "unit11", "department50", "team58"],
   ["group2", "unit10"],
   ["group5", "unit23", "department101"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to essentially remove all arrays that are subsets of some other array you can do:

```
$filteredSelections = collect($selections);
$filteredSelections = $filteredSelections->filter(
    fn ($selection) => $filteredSelections->first(
        fn ($item) => $selection !== $item && array_intersect($selection, $item) == $selection
   ) == null;
);
```